# How can I raise an exception for the programs' main function from a callback function?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, callback

I have a Python conundrum for you all

I want to raise an error in a callback function, and catch it in the main function:

```py
def main():
    try:
        box_ui = BoxUIHandler(...)
        
        bluetooth_handler = BluetoothHandler(box_ui, ...)
        bluetooth_handler.run() # Contains the program main loop
    except CriticalBluetoothError as e:
        print("Encountered critical error")
    except ButtonPressActivatedException as e:
        print("Button clicked, exiting...")
    finally:
        # Print stack trace
        # Perform cleanup


"""In another file"""
from gpiozero import LED, Button, GPIOZeroError

class BoxUIHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self._control_button_pin = Button(7, pull_up=True, bounce_time=0.1)
        self._control_button_pin.when_pressed = self._button_callback    

    def _button_callback(self):
        raise ButtonPressActivatedException("Button clicked, exiting...")
```

But raising this exception, from the callback function, does not reach the main function scope. I need a way to trigger the main function cleanup when this event occurs. How is this best done? Is there a way to raise an exception like this, or should another strategy be used altogether?

Best regards

/David

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not reach the main function scope"?

Comment: @PaulM. Ah yes, I meant that the `ButtonPressActivatedException` exception does not trigger in the main function